# AngularJS-2 custom delimiter

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do something similar to this `interpolateProvider` in `AngularJS 2` but can not find how to do this similarly

AngularJS 1.x https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
```

checking documentation for`AngularJS 2` can not find anything about this. sorry for my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available from angular 2.0.0-rc2 if I'm not mistaken, at least in current rc4 for sure. It is no longer global setting, but per-component metadata property.

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-comp",
    templateUrl: "some/url/some-file.html",
    ...,
    interpolation: ["{:!", "!:}"]
})
...
```

And in component's template `some/url/some-file.html` you can use those delimiters:

```
<div>{:!myExpression!:}</div>
```

BTW - thank you for the interesting question, I've found couple problems in my current project while I was trying to get an answer for you. :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer, until today.